# Can the United States withdraw/renegotiate from NAFTA without approval from the Senate?

Tags: united-states, constitution, treaty

The current political environment makes NAFTA worth considering. I haven't been able to find good research on this topic. I know that a country can withdraw from NAFTA by notifying the other parties to the agreement 6 months in advance. However, I haven't found any source that makes it clear how the United States would internally reach the decision. The US Constitution makes it clear the you need a 2/3 majority in the Senate to approve the ratification of a treaty. It's less clear whether the removal of or change of a treaty falls under that clause.

Comment: I thin NAFTA is not technically a treaty and therefore does not require legislative approval, but I need to confirm that

Comment: The treaty clause of the constitution requires a 2/3 majority in the senate for approval of ratification of a treaty.

Comment: You missed my point. If NAFTA is not technically a treaty then it doesn't fall under the treaty clause. This is sorta similar to what happened with the Iran deal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The North American Free Trade Agreement (NAFTA) is an [executive agreement](https://www.nolabels.org/blog/just-the-facts-treaty-vs-executive-agreement/), not a treaty.  As it was only passed with regular majorities of both chambers, it can be repealed or renegotiated with just the normal legislative process.

That is also true of [treaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_Clause#Repeal) though.  They can be repealed through the normal legislative process, as established in the [Head Money Cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_Money_Cases).  Renegotiation would require a new ratification, but repeal does not.

It's also possible that the president can unilaterally remove the United States from a treaty.  That's been done but never tested in court.  It's possible that executive agreements like NAFTA have more protection, since as law, they would require the normal legislative process to repeal.

Comment: That also means it would be subject to standard Senate cloture rules, correct?

Comment: Yes, anything in the normal legislative process, including a filibuster.  An executive agreement is effectively just a law that happens to describe interactions with foreign entities.

Comment: @BenCooper  Not necessarily.  Many trade agreements are "fast tracked" and that means the filibuster cannot be applied.